# Find the permutations where no element stays in place

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

I'm working with permutations where each element is different from its original location.  I would like an algorithm that given {an input length, row and digit}, will give me the output number.  Here's an example:

If the input length is four, then all the permutations of 0123 are:

```
0123,0132,0213,0231,0312,0321,
1023,1032,1203,1230,1302,1320,
2013,2031,2103,2130,2301,2310,
3012,3021,3102,3120,3201,3210
```

The permutations in which no digit is in the same place (every digit has moved):

```
1032,1230,1302,
2031,2301,2310,
3012,3201,3210
```

Numbering starts at 0 so if the input to the function is {4,0,0}, the output should be the 0th (leftmost) digit of the 0th (first) permutation.  First digit of 1032 is 1.

If the input is {4,1,1} then the output is the the second digit of 1230, which is 2.

The row number might be greater the nubmer of permutations.  In that case, take the remainder modulo the number of permutations (in the above case, row modulo 9).

In the c language would be great.

(It's not homework, it's for work.  Cuckoo hashing if you must know.  I'd like to randomly select the swaps that I'll be making at each stage to see if it's better than BFS when the number of tables is greater than two.)

Comment: This question really doesn't have a meaningful answer unless you define a partial order on the permutations. Who says that 0123 has to come before 0213?

Comment: Good comment Tyler.  I ordered the permutations from smallest to largest but I don't care about the order of the rows so long as the output is function of only the inputs and each row is equally likely.

Comment: If it's not homework, I'm sorry for tagging it as such. I have removed the tag again. I was very sure, especially since you made it community wiki. I apologize.

Comment: The problem as posed appears to require computing the desired permutation on the fly every time -- O(n!) work, kind of scary big (about 1/e of the n! permutations of n items are "derangements", i.e. have no fixed point, and of course the multiplicative constant doesn't change the big-O notation). Would it be OK to have one function "prepare the data", taking the input length argument, which does the O(n!) work once and for all; and a O(1) function to extract the desired digit given the data were already prepared?

Comment: BTW, you can find lots of materials about this problem on the web once you know that permutations without fixed points are known as "derangements". Most solutions involve generating all permutations and weeding out non-derangements, but there are also direct ones, e.g. http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61957.html , based on representing permutations as cycles and directly requiring them to have only cycles of length > 1. Also http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.746579.15 though the discussion & code leave much to be desired;-).

Comment: Knowing that it's called a derangement is useful, thanks.  I'll probably just generate all permutations, filter out the non-derangements, and store the answer for reuse.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brute-force approach in Python (you may use it to test your C implementation):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import ifilter, islice, permutations

def f(length, row, digit):
    """
    >>> f(4, 0, 0)
    1
    >>> f(4, 1, 1)
    2
    """
    # 1. enumerate all permutations of range (range(3) -> [0,1,2], ..)
    # 2. filter out permutations that have digits inplace
    # 3. get n-th permutation (n -> row)
    # 4. get n-th digit of the permutation (n -> digit)
    return nth(ifilter(not_inplace, permutations(range(length))), row)[digit]

def not_inplace(indexes):
    """Return True if all indexes are not on their places.

    """
    return all(i != d for i, d in enumerate(indexes))

def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    """Return the nth item or a default value.

    http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes
    """
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)

if __name__=="__main__":
    import doctest; doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: not_inplace = lambda indexes: all(starmap(ne, enumerate(indexes)))

Answer (score 1):

Why not just build a tree and iterate through it?

For example, if you have the digits `0123`, then you know that the left most digit can be only from the `set {1,2,3}`. This would act as your first level in your tree.

Then, if you go down the path beginning with 1, you only have three options, `{0, 2, 3}`. If you go down the path beginning with 2 in the first level, you only have two options `{0,3}` (since you can't use 1 in the second digit from the left and the 2 was already used (you could pop the 2 from your list of choices)), etc.

The thing to watch out for in this approach is if you get to the end of a branch with 3 being your only option, in which case, you would just delete it.

For `n > 10` generating all permutations and then filtering can become problematic. I think building out the tree would trim this significantly.

You can build the tree on the fly if need be. Your order can be defined by how you traverse the tree.