# Replace numpy.array values with randomly selected values from other rows in the array only

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I have the following array of shape (A, B) where A=4 and B=2 here:
`[[1 1] [2 2] [3 3] [4 4]]`
I want to modify the array so each row consists of randomly selected values from the other rows, with no repetition within the same row. An example result would be:
`[[3 2] [1 3] [2 4] [3 1]]`

I tried to use np.random.shuffle and np.random.choice but I can't figure out how to exclude the row itself and how to replace values per value instead of per row. np.random.shuffle leads to:
`[[4 4]    [2 2]    [3 3]    [1 1]]`
and np.random.choice gives me errors because my array is 2D and not 1D
I'm a beginner and I feel like this should be obvious but I've been racking my brain all day... Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Actually after I posted my answer I see that perhaps I am misunderstanding what your were trying to do.  You example result has lost the `4` from the first column.  Do you actually want that?

Comment: Yes, that's fine! The only key issue is that I don't want values from each row to be repeated in the same row in the new array. So oly 2s,3s and 4s in the first row, only 1s,3, ad 4s in the second row, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the values for an `A=N` matrix are always to be the values 1 to N, the following will generate a random matrix where the values come from that set but no row contains the one-based index of that row.

```
import random
N = 4
nums = list(range(1, N+1))
a = []
for irow in range(1, N+1):
    nums.remove(irow)
    a.append([random.choice(nums), random.choice(nums)])
    nums.append(irow)
print(a)
```

generates

```
[[3, 4], [4, 4], [4, 1], [1, 2]]
```

If you want to be sure that each column contains all of the possible values, but again with no value appearing in the row with the value equaling its one-based index.  The following (based of @BRivera's solution described in [Find the permutations where no element stays in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024245/find-the-permutations-where-no-element-stays-in-place)) should do the trick

```
import random

def generate_all_moved_permutation_tree(level, nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        raise RunTimeError('generate_permutation_tree must be called with a non-empty nums list')
    if len(nums) == 1:
        if level == nums[0]:
            return None
        else:
            return {nums[0]: {}}
    allowed_nums = list(nums)
    if level in allowed_nums:
        allowed_nums.remove(level)
    result = {}
    for n in allowed_nums:
        sublevel_nums = list(nums)
        if n in sublevel_nums:
            sublevel_nums.remove(n)
        subtree = generate_all_moved_permutation_tree(level+1, sublevel_nums)
        if subtree is not None:
            result[n] = subtree
    if len(result) == 0:
        return None
    return result

def pick_an_all_moved_permutation(all_moved_permutation_tree):
    n = random.choice(list(all_moved_permutation_tree))
    l = [n]
    sub_tree = all_moved_permutation_tree[n]
    if len(sub_tree) > 0:
        l.extend(pick_an_all_moved_permutation(sub_tree))
    return l
```

Examples

```
>>> t = generate_all_moved_permutation_tree(1, range(1,4))
>>> print(t)
{2: {3: {1: {}}}, 3: {1: {2: {}}}}
>>> t = generate_all_moved_permutation_tree(1, range(1,5))
>>> print(list(zip(pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t), pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t))))
[(2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 2), (1, 3)]
>>> print(list(zip(pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t), pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t))))
[(3, 4), (1, 1), (4, 2), (2, 3)]
>>> print(list(zip(pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t), pick_an_all_moved_permutation(t))))
[(3, 2), (4, 1), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: The first version works, thanks so much! The second version works too, but still gives me duplicate values in the same row, which isn't what I need. I'm looking at a way to edit it but if you know a fix I'd love to know!

Comment: Neither method precludes `a[i,0] == a[i,1]`.  They were just designed to guarantee that `a[i,0] != i` and `a[i,1] != i`.

Comment: I expect if you need to include `a[i,0] != a[i,1]` condition on both methods the best would be to choose the `a[i,0]` as given, and just repick `a[i,1]` if it comes up equal to `a[i.0]`

Answer (score 0):

Apply `np.random.shuffle` to each column individually

```
a = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]])
for col in range(a.shape[1]):
    np.random.shuffle(a[:,col])
print(a)
```

generated

```
[[1 4]
 [3 2]
 [4 1]
 [2 3]]
```

Comment: Good Answer. however for the general usecase of B columns use a for loop. `for col in range(a.shape[1]): np.random.shuffle(a[:,col])`

Comment: Thank you! However, I need it to exclude values from the row itself, so no 1's in the row that previously had 1's in it, etc. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have incorporated mcjeb's sugestion.

Comment: @Anne, Do you really want to have the ability to lose values from a column as you have indicated in your example?

Comment: Thank you! I'm still stuck on excluding values from the row itself, though.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, the goal is to create an array with random id's from the other row that influence the id's from the original array, so I'd want to exclude values from the row itself

Comment: @Malcolm Ideally I'd find both a version where the values of each column are preserved, and one where they are picked randomly and some values might be lost, because I'd like to try and look at both in my model. The goal in general is to create an array that contains rows with B values that represent other id's affecting that of the row id. It would be great to look at every id affecting an equal number of others (no loss in column) and to also randomise how many other ids they affect. (hope this makes sense!!!)

Comment: To get the first, I think you need solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024245/find-the-permutations-where-no-element-stays-in-place.  The second would require just converting each column to a set, excluding the current row from the set and making a random selection to populate that cell.  In either case, it really is a matter of regenerating a new array rather than altering the current one.  And unfortunately would require iterating in python rather than using a built-in fast numpy function.

Comment: Are your values always going to be 1 to N for `A=N`?

Comment: @Malcolm I tired but I'm not sure the solution you referred to would work in my case. I wouldn't know how but would it work to somehow use your solution and continue the loop until new_array and old_array have zero values in common?

Comment: Yes, the values will always be 1 to N @Malcolm

Comment: Then my second answer should be what you want.